# Proving coprimes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coprime

I understand that it is necessary to prove that the GCD = 1, and so the Euclidean Algorithm can be applied in some way, but I'm having trouble actually applying it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: so $d = 1,3,9.$  Then $n$ is a multiple of $9$  so that $n+1$ is not divisible by $9$ or $3$   and $d$   cannot be $3$ or $9$

Comment: " if d is an integer such that d|n+1 and d|n2+8 then d|9. I'm not too sure if this result is important for this part."  I'd say it makes you statement trivial!  As $9|n$ then $9$ is relatively prime to $n+1$ and $n^2 + 8$.  So if $n+1$ and $n^2+8$ have any divisors It can not be a (non-trivial) divisor of $9$.  But your statement says it *must* be a divisor of $9$.  That means the only common divisor is $1$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The previous part of the question had us proving for all integers n, if d is an integer such that d|n+1 and d|n2+8 then d|9

THen you are done!

Let $d = \gcd(n+1, n^2 +8)$.  Then by the previous part of the question $d|9$ so $d = 1, 3, 9$.  But if $9|n$ then $3|n$ and $3\not \mid n+1, 9\not \mid n+1, 3\not \mid n^2 + 8$ and $9\not \mid n^2+ 8$.

So $d$ divides both $n+1$ and $n^2 + 8$ the $d$ can not be equal to either $3$ or $9$.

That only leave $d = 1$.

So $\gcd(n+1, n^2 +8) =1$.

That's all there is to it.